# HTML5 Audio and JavaScript Audio Object Are not Working in iOS8 Beta

Tags: javascript, ios, html, audio, uiwebview

In iOS8 beta 2, Chrome (or any app using UIWebView) is not able to play HTML5 audio embedded in webpages.

For example, [this link](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-audio.php) works in older iOS. But in iOS8 betas, Chrome is not able to play the audio.

Also, a code like `var bckgrnd = new Audio('loop.mp3');` is not working in iOS8 beta, but works in older iOS releases.

Tested in iPAD2 running on iOS 8.0 (12A4297e).

Comment: This seems like a beta issue and should be reported back to the development team.

Comment: Try to use remote debug for your iPad (just connect it to Mac computer's Safari) and see console for more information. It could be as a temporary issue in beta, as a new major change. You need more information.

Comment: I have reported this bug. But as it is not possible to browse apple bugs, donno whether it is duplicate. It seems to be pretty straightforward issue. How come developers overlooked it.

Comment: we cannot see javascript errors in remote debugging.. can we ? (unless you redirect console logs to native codes and such hacks). html5 audio and Audio objects are working properly in iOS8 simulated devices when run from xcode6 beta